# Area 51 still showing deleted accounts in proposal page

Tags: bug, area-51, deleted-accounts

I just noticed something in [the proposal for Programmers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related):

> [image]

Clicking those leads to 404 error page, meaning those accounts have been deleted.

Apart of the ugly broken picture, this kind of expose information the users might have wanted to keep hidden, e.g. the author of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20275/mono-is-frequently-used-to-say-yes-net-is-cross-platform-how-valid-is-that) is anonymised, so having it linked in Area 51 renders this annonymity useless.

Proper fix in my opinion would be to remove those users from the list in Area 51 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but that's like *capture*, it says "Top Beta Users". So it won't be modified since the beta is over (special case is a *closed* beta, in which the image flairs are replaced with html ones), neither deleted users nor posts would be removed from this list.

But if a user (or a post) gets removed *during* the beta, they (or it) are properly removed from this list also.

Comment: Or it could be ........ "Caching"!

Comment: @Uni No, not caching. Those broken user cards will never go.

Comment: Yay finally not caching!